# Trying to get ipv4 from const sockaddr

Tags: c++, winsock, sockaddr-in

```
BOOL f_WSAConnect(SOCKET s, const sockaddr *name, int namelen, LPWSABUF lpCallerData, LPWSABUF lpCalleeData, LPQOS lpSQOS, LPQOS lpGQOS)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, name, "hi", MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
    return WSAConnect(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

I'm trying to obtain the ipv4 from const sockaddr when it's passed and i am not sure how i would approach it??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: I assume you are asking about the textual representation of ipv4 address? Use `inet_ntop`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html

Comment: @freakish from the `WSAConnect` we know this is Windows code and `inet_ntop` might be broken.

Comment: @PasserBy I don't know much about Windows, but a bit googling and it seems that there are equivalents: `InetNtop` or `WSAAddressToString` functions.

Comment: @PasserBy Hey, this question was actually properly tagged. We know this is Windows code from the winsock tag.

Comment: @DanielH Oops, didn't see that :). But that is not my point though :P. Wait, its edited in by Panta Rhei

Comment: @PasserBy Ah, you’re right, I missed that. But yes, it’s not really the point, although I *think* Windows sockets work very similarly to Unix ones.